# How to dial a phone number when a user taps on the number?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift app that I'm working on and on the contact us page, there's a bit that shows "Facebook Profile", Telephone Number, Email Address.

I have been told there's a way to have the code set up so when someone clicks on, for example the telephone number, it will open in iPhone phone dialer.

Any ideas where to find the code?

I've been sent this from someone who says they know the code, but when I asked him where the code goes, he said I just have to fiddle.

This is his code:

You need to add this code for each label you need to add for it an action in `viewDidLoad`:

```
yourlabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let rc = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.yourfunction))
rc.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
rc.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

yourlabel.addGestureRecognizer(rc)

func yourfunction(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let email = "foo@bar.com"

    let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:\(email)")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

And this is my code for the contact page (contactViewController.swift). Can someone have a look for me and help me out?

```
import UIKit

class contactViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var phone: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mail: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var facebook: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var instagram: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleContact: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var message: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // setup title
        self.title = "Contact us"

        // setup NavigationBar Color
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = navigationBarColor

        // setup side Bar
        if(sideBarPosition == "left"){
            self.setupLeftMenuButton()
        }
        else{
            self.setupRightMenuButton()
        }

        // setup page content
        scroll.bounces = false
        phone.text = phoneNumber
        mail.text = emailAdress
        facebook.text = facebookAcount
        instagram.text = instgramAcount
        address.text = adressLocal
        titleContact.text = titleContactus

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 20

        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: messageContact)
        attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

        message.attributedText = attrString
        message.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    }

    // setup left menu button icon
    func setupLeftMenuButton() {
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)

        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "menuleft.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState.normal)

        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(leftDrawerButtonPress), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 17) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)

        button.imageView?.tintColor = iconColor

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    // setup left menu button action
    func leftDrawerButtonPress(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.evo_drawerController?.toggleDrawerSide(.left, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // setup right menu button icon
    func setupRightMenuButton() {
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)

        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "menuright.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: UIControlState.normal)

        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(rightDrawerButtonPress), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 17) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)

        button.imageView?.tintColor = iconColor

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    // setup right menu button action
    func rightDrawerButtonPress(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.evo_drawerController?.toggleDrawerSide(.right, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll be better if you replace these "labels" with `UIButton` instead. The different coloring tell users that these string are clickable. Then you can just put everything in to an URL scheme and tell `UIApplication.shared` to open them:

```
@IBAction func dialNumber(_ sender: Any) {
    let phoneURL = URL(string: "tel://1234567890")!
    UIApplication.shared.open(phoneURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}

@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender : AnyObject) {
    let emailURL = URL(string: "mailto://user@domain.com")!
    UIApplication.shared.open(emailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: any idea in my code where your code would replace it?